# What is snipe on a thickness planer?

Tags: thickness-planer

I heard of something with snipe on a thickness planer. Is this something that they all will do? Is there a way to adjust the planer to keep that from happening? What techniques can be used to stop this on the piece that you are working on? Can this be a problem?

Comment: Not a dupe exactly because you asked so many specific things but this previous Q&A, [How can I minimize snipe while thickness planing?](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/66/how-can-i-minimize-snipe-while-thickness-planing) answers much of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snipe occurs when the leading or trailing edge of the board lifts a bit off the bed of the planer or the planer head, being supported only on one side if the cutters, drops a bit. The result is the last six inches or so of the board being cut more deeply than it/they should be.

There are a number of techniques to reduce/eliminate snipe, ranging from feeding boards through butted against each other so the head is supported more consistently, to lifting the far end of the board slightly so the feed roller pushes the board's end downward, to attaching sacrificial rails extending past the ends of the board to provide that support, to just letting the snipe occur and planning on not using the ends of the board at this thickness.

Comment: Tanks fur foxing thee errers, @graphus.

Comment: I never could catch one growing up, so I always wondered how they managed to get into my planer unnoticed.....

Comment: NP. Was that auto-correct on your phone?

Comment: Yep, auto-incorrect trying to be helpful...

Comment: The worst is when you get two or more snipes in your planer. They just argue pettily for hours.